# UI not update when list is changed on angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have a images list in my controller, when i load the page / controller, i invoke a method to populate this list, and than, the result of a list is displayed on interface ui through directive template, when i refresh the list in controller, by a $http resquest response(the same method which works on first load) the ui not reflect the list changes in controller.I do some searches on web, and the most searched instructions is refert $scope.$apply, o
    try
    to use this on list atribuition, but get an error, digest is already on progress.If i click on the refresh button of browser, works fine.But someone says that is not a good pratice use $scoep.$apply, but i don´ t imagine what´ s is wrong with the code.
I try use $timeout to, but not works.

**$scope.listaImagens = resp.data;**

```
angular.module('appImages').controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $location, $state, $notification, FileUploader, UrlService, $http, blockUI, ContextoService) {

            //List of images
            $scope.listaImagens = [];


            $scope.findAllImagens = function() {

                var urlImagensPagUsuario = $scope.urlImagem + "/findAllPaginadoByUsuario/" +
                    paginacaoDTO.pagRecordIndex + "/" + paginacaoDTO.pagBatchRecords + "/" + idUsuarioLocal;

                $http.get(urlImagensPagUsuario).then(function(resp) {

                    //HERE, receive the values, but not reflect on UI
                    $scope.listaImagens = resp.data;


                }, function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

            }

            //Busca as imagens
            $scope.findAllImagens();


            //Salva o usuario de contexto selecionado
            $scope.devePersistirUsuarioContexto = function(newUsuario) {

                if (newUsuario && newUsuario.idUsuario) {

                    $scope.urlUsuarioSelecionado = UrlService.makeUrl('usuarioselecionado');
                    var usuarioNew = {
                        "idUsuarioFk": newUsuario.idUsuario
                    };
                    $http.put($scope.urlUsuarioSelecionado, usuarioNew)
                        .then(function(resp) {
                            console.log('usuario de contexto atualizado');
                            $scope.findAllImagens();

                        }, function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                }

            }

        }
```

i try this examples:

```
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.listaImagens = resp.data;
        }, 0);

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.listaImagens = resp.data;
            $scope.$digest()
        }, 0);

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.listaImagens = resp.data;
            }
        }, 0);

       scope.$parent.$watch('selecionado', function() {
            if (scope.changeItemDrop) {
                scope.changeItemDrop(scope.selecionado);
            }
        }, true);   

       scope.$watch('selecionado', function() {
            if (scope.changeItemDrop) {
                scope.changeItemDrop(scope.selecionado);
            }
        }, true);
```

diretive declaration

```
<div class="floating-menu-paciente">
        <drop-down-combo placeholder="Escolha o paciente..." url="paciente" selecionado="pacienteContexto" fieldtext="pacienteNome" id="pacienteContexto" change-item-drop="devePersistirPacienteContexto(pacienteContexto)" />
    </div>
```

diretive

```
angular.module('appTmw').directive('dropDownCombo', ['UrlService', '$http', function(UrlService, $http, $timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E', //Diretiva restrita ao elemento
                    scope: {
                        placeholder: "@",
                        url: "@",
                        selecionado: "=",
                        fieldtext: "@",
                        changeItemDrop: "&"
                    },
                    templateUrl: '/assets/templates/dropDownCombo.html',
                    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

                        //Quando clica no item para escolha
                        scope.selectItem = function(resultado) {
                            scope.selecionado = resultado;
                            scope.showDrop = false;
                        };

                        scope.$watch('selecionado', function() {
                            if (scope.changeItemDrop) {
                                scope.changeItemDrop(scope.selecionado);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                };
```

template of directive

```
<div>
    <div class="combo">
        <input type="text" value={{selecionado[fieldtext].trim()}} placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-click="show()" ng-focus="true"> </input>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default srcCombo" ng-click="show()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- "showDrop" variável booleana da diretiva -->
    <div class="listagemCombo" ng-show="showDrop" ng-mouseleave="perdeuFoco()">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="resultado in resultados" ng-click="selectItem(resultado)">
                <td> {{resultado[fieldtext]}} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `$timeout` in the `put` handler, i.e.:

```
$http.put($scope.urlUsuarioSelecionado, usuarioNew)
                    .then(function(resp) {
                        console.log('usuario de contexto atualizado');
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.findAllImagens();
                        }, 0);
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
```

Or just try using the `evalAsync` which seems to be a potential solution for your case:

```
    $http.put($scope.urlUsuarioSelecionado, usuarioNew)
                    .then(function(resp) {
                        console.log('usuario de contexto atualizado');
                        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                            $scope.findAllImagens();
                        });
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
```

If you have a $watch firing the event and for some reason it isn't triggering the function you want to trigger, you can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to trigger it:

```
// in your $watch
scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
    $rootscope.$broadcast('myEvent');
});

// in your controller
$scope.$on('myEvent', function() {
    $scope.findAllImagens();
});
```

Comment: not works, i discover a thing, the method **devePersistirUsuarioContexto** is called from a scope.$watch inside a directive, any alteration if comes from this $watch not reflect on UI, i put a button and call a method from the button, and informations reflect on ui.

Comment: you should add the $watch portion to the code in the question, otherwise it's hard to tell what could be happening.

Comment: if you put console.logs inside and of the $watch before and after the if statement, do they both show up?

Comment: yes, i put a log and pass before if, inside if, e after if, and i try to use $watch with third parameter true _deep object dirty checking_,  parallel to this, i take im mind if the problem is about scope, i will made some tests with it.

Comment: I just added a version that will most likely work with your setup. If your problem is with scopes, you might want to broadcast an event to the rootscope and set a listener in your controller, that way you're not bound to any sandbox.

Comment: Now i found a way to solve the problem **$state.reload();** i don't know if is the best way, but works.